# Noob wondering about Linux experience expectations

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm installing Linux on an ASUS laptop. This is my first Linux experience and perhaps my expectations are off. I previously had Windows 8 on this laptop. This is not a dual boot though. I want Windows **completely and utterly gone**. I tried first with Mint Cinnamon x64 19.3. Install went smooth. Chose the option to completely wipe away all data. However when I start up the laptop instead of the OS I see a grub cli environment. I type "exit" and then it prompts me to choose Cinnamon, advanced options for Cinnamon, Windows from boot, or system options. No amount of removing boot options from removes windows as an option or makes mint os load up automatically. Goodbye Mint. Hello Ubuntu 19.10. Same issue. What do I do. OR!!! Is this a normal Linux experience?? And I always going to have to tell a linux machine to boot linux os on startup? IDK. Mucho helpo appreciatedo.

Comment: When you're installing Mint, make sure you format the drive Windows was on to start from scratch. Whenever Mint is installed correctly, it'll boot like Windows, minus potentially sitting at a menu for a few seconds (it will select the default then proceed on its own)

Comment: I found this similar question online: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/detecting-efi-files-and-booting-them-from-grub/38083. This helps skip the grub cli but the prompt is still there though there is a timer so after 9s it'll load Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for answering cutrightjm. I think that "sitting at a menu for a few seconds" is one of the new experiences I need to just come to terms with. I appreciate your time!!

Comment: It sounds like Mint installed to dual boot, which means your Windows is still there ( if you ever want to use it again ) . If you get more comfortable with Linux, you can follow this guide to make that menu not pop up - https://askubuntu.com/questions/157925/how-do-i-skip-the-grub-menu-on-a-dual-boot-system

Comment: yiu can configure grub to wait only very briefly